# zend load js file order

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, load

I include my jquery.js in layout.phtml,

```
  <?php $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl('js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js')); ?>
  <?= $this->headScript() ?>
```

and I include my own test.js in the IndexController,

```
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile('js/test.js');
```

but zend load the test.js file first, how could I make zend load jquery first ?   because I used query code in test.js file.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by using "offsetSetFile(order, file)".

```
$this->view->headScript()->offsetSetFile(10, $this->baseUrl('js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'));
$this->view->headScript()->offsetSetFile(20, $this->baseUrl('js/test.js'));
```

Comment: The offsetFile does not exist, I got this error:  
Uncaught exception 'Zend_View_Exception' with message 'Method "offsetFile" does not exist'

Comment: Sorry, its called: offsetSetFile :-)